# jQuery smartphone slide effect

Tags: jquery, slide, smartphone, jquery-effects

I have several divs on a page, all but one div is hidden

```
<div id="main"> ... content ... </div>
<div id="p1"> ...content... </div>
<div id="p2"> ...content... </div>
<div id="p2"> ...content... </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#p1').hide();
  $('#p2').hide();
  $('#p3').hide();
</script>
```

Now on the main page I have (say) 3 buttons / links.  I want to create a slide effect similar to a smartphone app (where when the button/link on the main page is clicked) it slides the main div off the screen to the left, and slide the associated div (eg p1) from the right side onto the viewport at the same time.

Now I can do this can either be done by replacing the contents of the main div (sliding the content of the div out and sliding the content of the p1 div into the div), or by sliding the entire div off screen and sliding the replacement div on).

Either option, I don't know how to accomplish this with jQuery.

Update:
As I have not received a solution yet, and I have been continuing my search for the answer, I did also find and (just ordered myself) : [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript: Making App Store Apps Without Objective-C or Cocoa](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/0596805780/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=comsoo02-20&linkCode=as2&camp=15121&creative=390961&creativeASIN=0596805780). Please note (full disclosure), that is an affiliate link (Amazon).  Though I am not promoting the book (haven't read it yet), it might be helpful to others.

Update 2: Kudos to stackoverflow, that affiliate link changed automatically to their affiliate code, so I linked that book for their benefit.  :) Either way, still hope that book helps someone, can't wait to receive my copy.

Comment: Check out jQuery mobile, it has the transitions you need

Comment: That looks very nice, (at least better documented) than the other framework I was playing with (jQTouch), however I really was looking for a simple jquery solution for the slide effect without the use of any frameworks/plugins.

Comment: the more I look at that framework, the more I like it.  (and yet the more I realize that it isn't really all that well documented).  But works well in all modern browsers as well as smart phones (with the exception of IE9 seems a bit flakey for look (moreso if you put it in compatibility mode). But it doesn't seem broken at least.  +1 for the link, still playing with it.  Didn't answer the question, but it is a good alternative.  I still would like to know if there is a quick n dirty solution without a framework (well except jquery of course)